# Uploading an image to picasa using a DataURL String

Tags: java, javascript, picasa

I am using HTML5 to create a 'camera' application that is totally web based. (without phonegap)

I now have a DataURL that I obtained as follows

```
canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480, 0, 0, 640, 480);
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Am I able upload this to picasa once I send this as a String to the server side?

The following code didnt work and gave me a "com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: OK
Not an image." exception. (imgStr is the DataURL above)

```
MediaByteArraySource imageByteArr = new MediaByteArraySource(imgStr.getBytes("UTF-16LE"), "image/jpeg");
myPhoto.setMediaSource(imageByteArr);
PhotoEntry returnedPhoto = client.insert(imagePostUrl, myPhoto);
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
The string looks like this "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAAHgCAYAAAA10dzkAAAgAElEQVR4Xuy92ZI...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to decode the string before it can be passed to MediaBytearraySource.

```
String imgStrBase64 = req.getParameter("photo").split(",")[1];          
byte[] dataBytes= Base64.decode(imgStrBase64);
MediaByteArraySource imageByteArr = new MediaByteArraySource(dataBytes, "image/jpeg");
```

Hope this helps someone.